# keep laptop on indefinitely

Tags: laptop, cpu

What happens when a laptop stays on indefinitely? Should you be buying a desktop box instead? What do you need to do to keep the laptop working correctly without sleeping or hibernating on a Windows 7/dell inspiron/ intel core i7

Answer (score 6):

There should be no issues with keep a laptop on indefinitely. Just keep it plugged in. You can set the power management and sleep settings however you like.

Comment: @Sam, you might want to remove the battery or discharge it completely once in while to prolong its life should you ever want/need to use it.

Comment: @martineau: That stopped mattering about a decade ago. The chargers in modern laptops are smart enough to maintain the battery in a life-maximizing float mode.